# How to properly handle 4K resolutions on Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, 4k-monitor

I have a 15.6" laptop with a 4K resolution running with Kubuntu 16.04. At first, everything was so small, so I forced the fonts DPI to 220. The display works correctly, but I have to manually increase images and fonts in certain applications (dolphin, phpstorm), and sometimes it is not configurable (KDialog for instance). It makes me think that this was probably not the best way to achieve my goal.

Another thing is that sometimes, I will connect my laptop to a 27" monitor (4K as well). When I do that, what is displayed is the exact same screen as my laptop's, meaning that everything (fonts, images) are bigger to fit the screen size. What I want is to have everything in the same size (on my laptop and the monitor), so that I can really benefit the space that the monitor offers. I put this issue in the same question as I think it might be related.

Answer (score 0):

Tomorrow a new Kubuntu version will be released, with improvements in HiDPI management.

If I were you, I would try your setup with the new version.

Comment: Would you know if increasing the fonts DPI is the right way to have a correct display? Or is there another option somewhere else? Is there a new option in Kubuntu 17.04 to do just that?

Comment: Qt and Plasma keep being improved to handle HiDPI cases, although hardware also has to work with software, etc.  Maybe [this document](https://www.girialam.com/2016/02/kubuntu-and-hidpi-screen/) can help you.

Comment: Recently there is more information, and a petition about details, in those articles:

1) ["Do you know of any HiDPI issues?"](https://blog.hetzenecker.me/2017-05-15-hidpi-issues/)
    

2) ["Making Hi-DPI awesome"](https://blog.hetzenecker.me/2017-05-15-hello-gsoc/)

Answer (score 0):

One user named Markc wrote:

> I have a QHD (3200x1800) 13" laptop and I simply set the font DPI to
>   232 and the icons/advanced up to 48 and 128, desktop 256.

---

If anyone wants to read his full text, [it was](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/software/desktop-linux/966619-the-state-of-kde-plasma-for-summer-2017?p=966823#post966823):

> I don't understand the HiDPI "problem" with plasma. I have a QHD
>   (3200x1800) 13" laptop and I simply set the font DPI to 232 and the
>   icons/advanced up to 48 and 128, desktop 256, job done. Even Firefox
>   and Thunderbird look just fine since late last year. Been doing this
>   for 3 years and for the last year it's been close to perfect.
>
> I have tried the scaling setup in SystemSettings/Display and
>   Monitor/Displays but that sucks. It often looks fat and ugly whereas
>   my old-school approach has a leaner less bloated but still nice font
>   and icon size look. I don't want EVERYTHING blown up by x2 or even
>   x2.25 (whatever), just the fonts and icons. Leave a 1px border at a
>   lean 1px rather than a sometimes blurry fat ~2px.